# Stability Function system

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, lyapunov-functions

Hi I have this question

> For the system
> $$\begin{align}
> \dot p_1 &= -p_1 + 6p_2 \\
> \dot p_2 &= -7p_2+(p_1+p_2)\cos p_1 
> \end{align}
> $$
> Use the function  $L(p)=\frac{1}{2}(p_1^2 + p_2^2)$ ,and show that the origin is locally asymptotically stable.

What I have done so far:

1. Differentiated $L(p)$ to get $\dot L(p)$
2. Substituted in the values of $\dot p_1$ and $\dot p_2$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Pictures should not be used for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. I have [edit]ed your question to reflect this principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since

$$x_1^2 + x_2^2 \ge 2x_1x_2 \implies x_1x_2 \le \frac{1}{2}x_1^2+\frac{1}{2}x_2^2$$

for all real numbers $x_1,x_2$, we have

\begin{align}\dot V(x)&=-x_1^2+x_1x_2+(x_1x_2+x_2^2)\sin x_1-3x_2^2\\&\le
-x_1^2+\frac{1}{2}x_1^2+\frac{1}{2}x_2^2+\left(\frac{1}{2}x_1^2+\frac{1}{2}x_2^2+x_2^2\right)|\sin x_1|-3x_2^2\\&=
-\frac{1}{2}x_1^2-\frac{5}{2}x_2^2+\left(\frac{1}{2}x_1^2+\frac{3}{2}x_2^2\right)|\sin x_1|\\&\le-x_2^2\\&
\le 0 
\end{align}

as $|\sin x_1|\le 1$. Global asymptotic stability follows from $\dot V(x) < 0$ when $(x_1,x_2)\neq 0$.

Comment: $\dot{V}(x) \leq 0$ doesn't show global asymptotic stability. It merely shows that the origin is stable.

Comment: That is true, for global asymptotic stability we need $\dot V(x) < 0$ for $x\neq 0$. I have updated my answer.

Comment: You've stated the condition but your answer is still inadequate to show this conclusion. Moreover, from your answer $\dot{V} \leq -x^2_2, x_1\neq 0$.

Comment: This approach shows that $\dot V(x)$ is negative semidefinite. As the test function $V(x_1,x_2)$ is positive definite, a technique from ODE theory known as the [LaSalle's invariance principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaSalle%27s_invariance_principle#Local_version_of_the_Krasovskii.E2.80.93LaSalle_principle) would show global asymptotic stability. However, when I apply this technique, I get the set $S = \{ (x_1,x_2) | \dot{V}(x_1,x_2) = 0 \}$ is not equal to $S = \{ (x_1,x_2) | x_1 = 0 \}$ or $S = \{ (x_1,x_2) | x_2 = 0 \}$.

Comment: I am unable to show that S does not contain any trajectories besides $x(t)=0$ for $t>0$. It could be that the proposed approach to show globally asymptotically stable is in Lutz's answer. I could have incorrectly analyzed something which would have provided globally asymptotically stability through the LaSalle invariance principle.

Comment: In order to check the asymptotic stability, we need $\dot{V} < 0$ if this is the case plus $V(\cdot)$ is radially unbounded, then the origin is globally asymptotically stable  which is the case in this system according to @Lutz's answer.

Comment: If $\dot{V} \leq 0$, Lyapunv theory fails to draw any conclusion about asymptotic stability but it doesn't say the origin is unstable. In this case, we use LaSalle's invariance principle to show that even $\dot{V} \leq 0$, we may conclude the origin is indeed asymptotically stable.

Comment: Actually, I'm surprised how the OP accepted your answer without further clarifications.

Answer (score 3):

As $ |\sin x_1|\le1$ you get
$$\begin{align}
\dot V&\le -x_1^2+x_2x_1+|x_2x_1|\,|\sin x_1|+x_2^2|\sin x_1|-3x_2^2
\\
&\le -x_1^2+x_2x_1+|x_2x_1| +x_2^2 -3x_2^2
\\
&\le -x_1^2+2|x_1x_2|-2x_2^2
\\
&=-(|x_1|-|x_2|)^2-|x_2|^2
\\
&<0
\end{align}$$
for $(x_1,x_2)\ne(0,0)$.

Comment: why did you take the absolute value for $|\sin x_1|$?

Comment: Because you want an upper bound (that is still negative) for $\dot V$. The upper bound for a product is the product of the absolute values of the factors.

Comment: Could you please show more details in how did you get the final result?

Comment: I was just completing the square of the first two terms, this uses part of the third term. Other variants are possible. All show that this quadratic form is negative definite.

Comment: I mean how did you transform $(x_1x_2+x^2_2)\sin x_1 \rightarrow 2|x_1x_2|$?

Comment: Note that I also used up one $-x_2^2$ in this process. Everything else is as per the first comment. I added the small steps for it. You can get better upper bounds, but they will not be that nicely polynomial.

Comment: that makes sense. Thanks. I feel this deserves to be the correct answer because the accepted answer doesn't show $\dot{V} < 0$ but yours does.